# Rescuing Wordpress Data in MySQL and turning it into a Wordpress Export File

Tags: mysql, wordpress, file-conversion

I've asked about [this](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/how-can-i-get-help-to-import-my-old-wordpress-blog-to-wordpresscom) on the Wordpress.org site and have not received an answer.  I've been searching and trying to get information on it, but I can't get anything usable.

I have a Wordpress blog on my own site, hosted by Westhost.  It was running Wordpress 2.7 (I never got a notice about upgrading and now they have 3.x at that hosting service).  At some point in the past six weeks, my blog disappeared.  Now when I go to the main page, I get a blank page - even "show source" gives no text or html.

I was told to do backups, then uninstall Wordpress 2.7, then re-install it, then upgrade to 3.x.  This won't work.  I uninstalled 2.7, and then the option to install 2.7 vanished.  I had to have them restore a backup from earlier to make sure everything was still there.  I've tried installing 3.x directly, but it won't install because it sees the directory "wordpress" in MySQL's data directories.  I considered backing that DB up or renaming it, then installing 3.x, then overwriting 3.x with the 2.7 DB, but I've been told files are incompatible and the upgrade would be necessary to convert the older 2.7 files and data to the newer formats.

I can, however, access all my Wordpress data (posts, comments, blobs that are pictures) in MySQL, so I can dump the database and then use Perl scripts to do whatever I need to convert it.

I don't want to have to keep spending time dealing, in the future, with upgrading and managing Wordpress, so I'd like to just move my blog to Wordpress.com.  The problem is they can import Wordpress export files, but not MySQL data.  I can't even find information on how to ask them if they'll import it for a fee.  (I did find info on **exporting** to other formats for a fee.)

Since Wordpress.com does not allow access to MySQL directly, or through phpAdmin, or Adminer, the only way I can see (other than manual cut and paste and so on) to get my data into a Wordpress.com blog is to have a Wordpress export file.

But I can't find any information on the format or spects for an export file.

I need to find a way to convert my data from the MySQL tables used in Wordpress 2.7 to a Wordpress export file.  If I could find specs, I could do that with Perl scripts.  But I'm open to other ideas.

How can I convert the DB info in MySQL to a Wordpress Export File?

(I don't care about things like any themes I had - I only want to import posts, with formatting and links and images, and comments.)

Comment: Just do this, install xampp on your local machine, then export wordpress database using PHPmyadmin, import it into your local machine, use old source file of wordpress 2.7 and change config to point to your local db, once done, change wp_option table to point url to localhost, and then you can login wordpress admin in local machine, export wordpress using wordpress admin...

Comment: @SumitGupta: You sound like you've done this before.

Comment: I do 5-10 wordpress on monthly basis :).

Comment: Okay, just to save me a bit of time, xampp includes all I need, other than Wordpress 2.7 (and Bitnami would install Wordpress, but it'd be the latest version, so I can't use that).  Am I correct in that?

Comment: xampp, is apache, mysql, php included tool for developer, if you already have ability to run wordpress locally, then don't install it, and use it. the idea was to setup wordpress locally and then fetch it's data, for export online with fresh install.

Comment: @SumitGupta: Good idea, but I did the basic install of xampp and Wordpress.  I set up wp-config.php to log in to the MySQL as root (and it was unable to create the wordpress database), but the problem is, even with what seems to be a stock install, I get slews of errors from Wordpress.  The main page will come up, but no others.  I'll have to handle this on the WP forums and see what I get.  I'll include notes later for others.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39396/discussion-between-sumit-gupta-and-tango)